# Can construction adhesive be used to fix this hole?

Tags: drywall, adhesive, patching-drywall

This bathroom towel bar came off and left an affected area of about 3 inches in diameter. I know the "proper" way to fix this is to cut out a square surrounding the affected area, then put a support frame behind, then cut out a new drywall piece and screw it on, then patch the edge with dry wall compound, sand, and paint. Though I wonder if I can clear the area (removing parts that stick out beyond the drywall plane), and use construction adhesive to fill the hole, sand, and paint. Has anyone tried that? Do you recommend it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does not really look that bad.  Some light tapping, drywall mud and mesh tape should do.  Smooth and paint.

Comment: General observation: If you need extra-wide mesh tape, it's possible to cut a piece out of window screening and embed it into a thin layer of mud in lieu of adhesive.

Comment: @crip659 is drywall mud the same as drywall compound?

Comment: yes, mud == compound in the drywall world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone used improper wall anchors, that are to weak for the job.

Someone then ripped them out of the drywall.

You could use construction adhesive but it will not end up looking good.

Repair:

Use a drywall filler in a tube and fill the holes.

Gently tap the ripped-out parts back, and coat with drywall mud. Paint over that.

Now use stronger drywall anchors like this type or similar (source Amazon), where it spreads the wings behind the drywall for stronger hold. This type is dependent on drywall thickness.

[image: drywall]

[image: anchor]

This type is the stronger, and it does not depends on the drywall thickness unlike the other model

Comment: Picture attributions?

Comment: @MichaelKaras fixed

Comment: Better yet: attach your towel bar to wall studs, so that the next time someone trips and grabs onto it, or the next time a child spends more than 5 minutes in the room, it won't get ripped out again.

Comment: Always minimize the use of drywall toggles for attaching _anything_ to a wall. The more screws into studs, the less likely the thing is to fall out of the wall.